# Conditionally substring based on the location of a specific character to create a new variable [mutate; case_when; str_locate_all problem]

Tags: r, case, purrr, stringr, mutate

I am trying to create a couple new variables such as `region_code` and `landowner_code` based on the result of substring from another variable `site_name`. The original `site_name` is mostly but not always segmented with the "-" character, like "ABCDE" in `df2`. For these anomalies I need to deal with separately.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(site_name = c("S10-020-38",
                                "M4-010-8",
                                "P10-005-001"))

# df with an anomaly "ABCDE"
df2 <- data.frame(site_name = c("S10-020-38",
                                "M4-010-8",
                                "P10-005-001",
                                "ABCDE"))
```

I am expecting the result to be (from df2):

| site_name | region_code | landowner_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S10-020-38 | 10 | 10-020 |
| M4-010-8 | 4 | 4-010 |
| P10-005-001 | 10 | 10-005 |
| ABCDE | ABCDE | ABCDE |

I have been able to do `region_code` successfully:

```
# region code -- this works
df2 %>% mutate(
  region_code = case_when(
    site_name == "ABCDE" ~ "ABCDE",
    TRUE                 ~ str_sub(site_name, 
                                   start = 2, 
                                   end = str_locate(site_name, "-")[,1]-1)))
```

but not `landowner_code`, even if I exclude the anomaly record:

```
# site code -- this doesn't work, but why?

str_locate_all(df2$site_name, "-")

df2 %>% 
  head(3) %>%
  mutate(
    site_code = case_when(
      site_name == "ABCDE" ~ "ABCDE",
      TRUE                 ~ str_sub(site_name, 
                                     start = 2, 
                                     end = str_locate_all(df2$site_name, "-") %>% map(~ .x[2,2])
      )))
```

Running the `landowner_code` code gives an error message:

> Error in `mutate()`:
> Problem while computing `site_code = case_when(...)`.
> Caused by error in `.x[2, 2]`:
> subscript out of bounds

But why out of bounds? From `str_locate_all(df2$site_name, "-")`I believe each element in the list is a 2x2 matrix? Or how do I create `landowner_code` variable properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub` instead of your combination of `str_sub` and `str_locate_all`. `gsub` returns the same text if the pattern isn't matched, the exact way you want to deal with anomalies, and in my opinion, makes the code easier to understand.

```
pattern = "[A-Z]{1}([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+"
df2 %>%
  mutate(region_code = gsub(pattern, "\\1", site_name),
         landowner_code = gsub(pattern, "\\1-\\2", site_name))

    site_name region_code landowner_code
1  S10-020-38          10         10-020
2    M4-010-8           4          4-010
3 P10-005-001          10         10-005
4       ABCDE       ABCDE          ABCDE
```

**REGEX explanation:**

- pattern `[A-Z]{1}`: matches any upper case letter exactly one time
- pattern `([0-9]+)-`: after that, any number of algarisms before a `-`. The `()` indicate a group, that can be referred by the `"\\1"` syntax in the second argument. This gets repeated three times, the last one without `()` because we don't need to refer to it later.
- `"\\1"`: return only the first group
- `"\\1-\\2"`: return the first group, followed by a '-', followed by the second group

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. Some of my real `site_name` have appended characters, either with or without space e.g. `S10-020-38 (abc)` (space before **(abc)**) or `S10-020-38(abc)` (no space before **(abc)**).  The suggested pattern results in `10(abc)` (no space before **(abc)**) for `landower_code`. Some other site_names are like `S10-020-38 (P10-020-38)` which results in `10(10)` for `region_code`. How to amend the gsub pattern?

Comment: You can add a `.*` at the end, that will match anything after the last digits end, if there exists anything (that's why the `*` and not `+`. Also, you can add an anchor `^` at the beginning to match the letter only at the beginning of the string. `pattern = "^[A-Z]{1}([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+.*"`.